# No view all or create all option on Account Permissions page

Tags: community, profile, trialforce

I cloned a profile from Community profile and edited on the cloned custom profile.
However, I could not see the "view all", "modify all" options on that profile.
I'm working on a TSO (trial force org)
Any idea?
Thanks

[image: inline]

[image: inline]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BfNQAU&title=customer-community-user-licenses-have-modify-view-all-permissions-on-custom-objects-but-plus-and-partners-do-not

> Customer Community user licenses have Modify/View All permissions on custom objects but Plus and Partners do not
>
> Communities
>
> Last updated 27 days ago ·Reference W-3809874 ·Reported By 2 users
>
> IN REVIEW
>
> Summary
>
> At this time it is possible to grant View All and Modify All permissions on profiles using the lesser Customer Community user licenses. Licenses above this type (Customer Community Plus and Partner Community) do not have these permissions available.
>
> Repro
>
> 1. Create a profile based on the Customer Community user license
> 2. Once the profile is created edit the new profile and access a custom object permission.
> 3. Note you are able to set Modify All and View All for the custom object
> 4. Now do the same steps for the Customer Community Plus or Partner Community user licenses.
> 5. You will notice that the View All and Modify All permissions are not available for custom objects.
>
> Workaround
>
> None. If you upgraded a user from the lesser Customer Community to either Customer Community Plus or Partner Community and need to revert the change, you will need to deactivate the user and then create a new one using the previous license type. This is discussed here:
>
> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_upgrade_licenses.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

Community user licenses have less functionality than standard licenses.  Among the restrictions -- you can't View All or Modify All on objects.